# Access 2010 - How to make multiple queries with changing the criteria automatically

Tags: vba

I have a question concerning a "serie of queries". After searching the internet for hours, I am really lost!
I want to make 200 queries with changing criteria (the values from the field "City"). How can I tell Access "please repeat the query on the fields "X", "Y" and "Z" by grouping by the field "City".  Is there a simple way to make Access pull the Values of "City" from a list and creating a query having the same name like the Value in "City". And doing that for all 200 Cities?
Unfortunately, I am fairly new to Access and VBA. Any help would be HIGHLY APPRECIATED :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.Do you have any concrete examples?

Comment: Could you also provide the query you want to execute 200 times?

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM tbl1
WHERE (((tbl1.City)="New York"));

Comment: Just a simple select query. And the WHERE clause (= the value of the field "City") should change from query to query to give me 200 different queries as a result. One for each Value of "City" and named after it. Sorry, I think I an kind of newbie in a quite advanced forum! but thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

A few options. You could open a recordset containing all your Cities, then loop through it and you get a buncha queries:

```
dim s as string
dim sql as string
dim r as new adodb.recordset
'populate r with SELECT * FROM tblCities (code not shown here)
s = r![City]
sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE City = '" & s & "';"
debug.print sql
'do whatever you want with the contents of sql
```